# Rails 3: Feed is taking too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a twitter-like feed in my web app. I've tried to optimize the query as much as possible but it still freezes when it's loading the "tweets" from PostgresSQL database.

Twitter, github, facebook, feeds are so smooth and fast.

What's the best way to accomplish that?

Regards.

**Edit: the code is the one in railstutorial.org.
http://railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec:scopes_subselects_and_a_lambda

```
# Return microposts from the users being followed by the given user.
  scope :from_users_followed_by, lambda { |user| followed_by(user) }

  private

    # Return an SQL condition for users followed by the given user.
    # We include the user's own id as well.
    def self.followed_by(user)
      followed_ids = user.following.map(&:id).join(", ")
      where("user_id IN (#{followed_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id",
            { :user_id => user })
    end


# Table name: microposts
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  content    :string(255)
#  user_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#
```

Sorry for not providing enough information.**

Comment: What is the query you've currently got?

Comment: You want optimization advice but provide no code, no database schema, no information at all except "My code is slow when hitting the database"?

Comment: How long does this query typically take to run?  How many times in a pageload are you running this query? It is more likely an issue where you are sending a lot of these types of queries than a singular one slowing everything down.  Can you include some controller code showing how you load followers? Do you only ever load one user's followers or are you loading lots of users followers?

Comment: I don't quite understand what code do you want me to provide. IT takes 9326.5ms to load 301 microposts from the database. Is it too much time for that amount of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you put any index on your tables?